Http 403 error when reading parquet file using duckdb directly from minio path
I have to read last 5 files from specific bucket/filepath in Minio. The file name is defined numerically like "1. parquet", "2. parquet" etc...
I have used Boto3 Client to connect to Minio. Problem is I am getting HTTP error 403 when querying the file using read_parquet method and passing the bucket/filepath directly. So just to verify, I downloaded 1 file and tried querying the same. It worked properly and I got the output. I need to understand where is the problem as code to connect minio is similar. code to read the parquet file directly is as below.
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import duckdb
import re

# Initialize S3 client
s3 = boto3.client(
's3',
endpoint_url='http://your-minio-endpoint',  # e.g., "http://localhost:9000"
aws_access_key_id='your-access-key',
aws_secret_access_key='your-secret-key',
use_ssl=False  # Set to True if you're using HTTPS
)

bucket_name = 'bucketname'
prefix = 'ABCD/Year=2024/Date=20240816/'

# List objects
response = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix)
files = [obj['Key'] for obj in response.get('Contents', []) if 
obj['Key'].endswith('.parquet')]

# Extract numbers and sort
def extract_number(filename):
    match = re.search(r'(\d+)\.parquet$', filename)
    if match:
       return int(match.group(1))
    return None

files_with_numbers = [(f, extract_number(f)) for f in files if extract_number(f) is not None]
files_with_numbers.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# Get the last n files
n = 5  # or any number you need
last_n_files = [file[0] for file in files_with_numbers[:n]]
print("Last", n, "files:", last_n_files)

# Query files with DuckDB
conn = duckdb.connect()
dfs = []
for file in last_n_files:
    file_path = f"s3://{bucket_name}/{file}"
    query = f"SELECT * FROM read_parquet('{file_path}')"
    df = conn.execute(query).fetchdf()
    dfs.append(df)
    print(f"Data from file {file}:")
    print(df.head())

all_data = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print("Concatenated DataFrame:")
print(all_data.head())


this isnt a pandas problem - your issue lies with duckdb fetching the data

agree!!! any ways to address the issue
